# Calculate in deeper list levels R

Tags: r, lapply

Imagine, I have list of two levels:

```
lll <- list()
lll[[1]] <- list(1:10, 1:5, 1:2)
lll[[2]] <- list(10:20, 20:30)
lll
 [[1]]
 [[1]][[1]]
  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

 [[1]][[2]]
 [1] 1 2 3 4 5

 [[1]][[3]]
  [1] 1 2


 [[2]]
 [[2]][[1]]
  [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

 [[2]][[2]]
  [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

I want calculate means of these sequences. I have written a little function, which works fine:

```
func <- function(list.list){
     lapply(1:length(list.list), function(i) mean(list.list[[i]]))
}

lapply(lll, func)
```

I don't like in this function, that I have to use anonymous function. 
It gets even more complicated when I have list of 3 levels.

Maybe you know better ways to make calculations in which anonymous function would not be included? Should I use higher-order functions (`Map`, `Reduce`)?

I know how to write `for` cycle, but in this case it isn't an option.

Comment: It's amazing how from 4-lines code you can reach 1-line!

Comment: is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Do you need a way to calculate the mean of vectors at any level of depth, or just 2 levels ?

Comment: I even didn't thought about that, digEmAll! As you mentioned, it would be great to have functional, in which I could input any function(`mean`, `sum` and etc.) and calculate this function at any level of depth. But I haven't tried it yet, so ask for your help would be shame on me.:))

joel.wilson, your answer helped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution (using rapply = recursive apply) working at any level of depth :

```
lll <- list()
lll[[1]] <- list(1:10, 1:5, 1:2)
lll[[2]] <- list(10:20, 20:30)

res <- rapply(lll,mean,how='replace')
> res
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 5.5

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 1.5


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 15

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 25
```

Setting argument `how='unlist'` you will get :

```
res <- rapply(lll,mean,how='replace')
> res
[1]  5.5  3.0  1.5 15.0 25.0
```

Comment: Wow, never heard about `rapply` function. Clearly I need spend more time on reading about functional programming in R. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Lesley.H: glad to be of help ;)

Comment: @digEmAll this is great code... never knew of `rapply()`.. +1!